# Creating product specific options

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.0.1, custom-options

I work on a Magento website and I recently saw a website (www.carid.com) that has a popup menu for specific products. So for example if a product is headlight specific you can click on the the product options and you'll be prompted with a menu that lets you pick year, make and model for that specific product type (for this example it being headlight).

Can this be done in Magento via backend? Here is an example of what I'm trying to explain, click on "Select Product Options":

```
http://www.carid.com/spyder/custom-headlights.html
```

I was thinking about perhaps creating custom options but they aren't dependent on each other, is there a way to create a similar feature on Magento?

Answer (score 1):

To create this exact functionality you will need some customization. This seems to work like magento's Bundle Products but the difference is it gets a list of products with the specifications you select as opposed to specifying certain aspects of the bundle product and also there is no dependency.

Again custom options would not provide this exact functionality and like you said there is no dependency.

As i said, unfortunately this can't be done with magento out of the box

Comment: Ok I figured as much, how would I go about customization ?